# Can the client side access socket assigns?

Tags: javascript, websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework, channel

I know that in Phoenix Channel the server can keep states via socket assigns, e.g.

```
def join("room:lobby", payload, socket) do
  socket = socket
    |> assign(:message, Enum.random(@messages))
    |> assign(:albums, [])
  {:ok, socket}
end
```

However, I haven't been able to find out whether there's any way for the client to access those assigns.

My confusion is that, if a socket connection is supposedly kept between the server and the client until it's terminated, shouldn't the client be able to access what's in this connection as well?

Or is it the case that all these assigns are only kept in a **server-side process**, and therefore are inaccessible to the client, even though the client does maintain a connection to the server in some way?

If that's the case, it seems the server must explicitly broadcast to the client whatever assigns it has stored, if it wants to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My confusion is that, if a socket connection is supposedly kept
>   between the server and the client until it's terminated, shouldn't the
>   client be able to access what's in this connection as well?

`assigns` is just a key in a struct:

```
defmodule Phoenix.Socket
  ...
  ...
  defstruct assigns: %{},
            channel: nil,
            channel_pid: nil,
            endpoint: nil,
            handler: nil,
            id: nil,
            joined: false,
            join_ref: nil,
            private: %{},
            pubsub_server: nil,
            ref: nil,
            serializer: nil,
            topic: nil,
            transport: nil,
            transport_pid: nil
```

https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.4.0/lib/phoenix/socket.ex#L181

That struct is NOT in the connection.  Rather the struct is a scratchpad that the server uses to store relevant info about a particular connection.  According to the [Channels docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/channels.html#overview):

> To start communicating, a client connects to a node (a Phoenix server)
>   using a transport (eg, Websockets or long polling) and joins one or
>   more channels using that single network connection. One channel server
>   process is created per client, per topic. ***The appropriate socket
>   handler initializes a %Phoenix.Socket for the channel server*** (possibly
>   after authenticating the client). The channel server then holds onto
>   the %Phoenix.Socket{} and can maintain any state it needs within its
>   socket.assigns.
>
> Once the connection is established, each incoming message from a
>   client is routed, based on its topic, to the correct channel server.
>   If the channel server asks to broadcast a message, that message is
>   sent to the local PubSub, which sends it out to any clients connected
>   to the same server and subscribed to that topic.

--

> It seems the server must explicitly broadcast to the client whatever
>   assigns it has stored, if it wants to?

Yes.

You can check out how a server might use assigns in this [ElixirCasts.io video](https://elixircasts.io/exploring-phoenix-assigns) (starting at 4:15).

Comment: Thanks. And that episode is literally where I copied my example from haha. It doesn't say anything about my question though.